# Issue with Accessing facebook page using restfb

Tags: facebook, restfb

I am using restfb to access Facebook public pages like [this](https://www.facebook.com/cocacola),

But I am facing issue to access pages like [this](https://www.facebook.com/pages/WellStar-Paulding-Hospital/444591015570144)

Here is the code:

```java
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("cocacola", Page.class);
System.out.println("User name: " + user.getName());
System.out.println("Page likes: " + page.getLikes());
```

**Issue:** I am not sure what I should pass in `fetchObject` method. If I pass `"WellStar-Paulding-Hospital"` for a url like `"https://www.facebook.com/pages/WellStar-Paulding-Hospital/444591015570144"`, it throws an error with the message:

> Some of the aliases you requested do not exist

Comment: You have code, and you are facing issues. Now you need to tell us which issues.

Comment: Issue is i can access "cocacola" with out any issues and it has url  "https://www.facebook.com/cocacola", but issue is accessing a page with url like "https://www.facebook.com/pages/WellStar-Paulding-Hospital/444591015570144". I am not sure what i should pass in fetchObject method. If i pass "WellStar-Paulding-Hospital" it throws error with message -- "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:"

Comment: No, the issue is not that something works. It is that something doesn't work, and I'm asking in which way it doesn't work. Is there an error? Is the information wrong? Is it blank?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the similar issue. `facebookClient.fetchObject("somePageName",Page.class)` was throwing the exception you have mentioned.

I noticed that the code runs properly for any page which is of the format

A) facebook/somePageName

however the pages with url like below do not work:

B) facebook/pages/somePageName/2192383292

Any page which does not have a Page Username set in the PageInfo follows the type B url and is not accessible with the code. To resolve the issue, ask the page admin to edit the pageInfo and set a Username for the page. E.g for your case lets say the username specified is WellStartPauldingHospital.
In that case the url to access the page will become

https://www.facebook.com/WellStarPauldingHospital

and you will be able to use the code as follows:

```
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("WellStartPaulindHospital",Page.class);
```